# Is it possible to not destruct obj while destructor is running?

Tags: c++

If I override the destructor of my class, is it possible to made some check in it if that instance should be killed or sent to a pool? I want to make simple to reuse the obj, the user only needs to free it (or leave for compiler) and the destructor would check if that's reusable.

```
ReusableClass::~ReusableClass() {
  if (x == 1) {
    // abort destructor, send to pool
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider something like a smart pointer with a custom deleter.

Comment: Do you want to reuse the object itself, or merely the memory/space occupied by the object?

Comment: I want to reuse the object

Comment: Take a look at [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting) and [std::shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the destructor of an object started running the object is considered dead: 12.4 [class.dtor] paragraph 14:

> Once a destructor is invoked for an object, the object no longer exists; ...

Answer (score 0):

Of course not - you would have no *reference* to the object either - how could you recycle the object then?

So solve that problem and you'll have the solution. Use a smart pointer and store the reference wherever you actually need it, perhaps in a map or owned by another object (this is now looking more like a Java solution, for instance), or manually delete it (this is less smart) when ready.